# What is the default Set/List implementation with Collectors in Java 8 Stream API?

Tags: java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have below code snap with Java 8.

```
 List<Employee> employees = DataProvider.getEmployees();
 Set<Employee> set = employees.stream().filter(emp -> {
                System.out.println(emp.getName());
                return emp.getName().equals("Vishal");
            }).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

I just want to know which implementation of `Set` it is using by default when we use `Collectors.toSet()` (refer above example)?

Also, is there any way to tell the Java API to use a particular implementation (for example, `HashSet`)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `toSet()` collector does not specify which implementation it uses; you get a `Set`, that's all.

If you want a specific kind of set, use `toCollection()` and provide a factory method for your set:

```
    ...collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
```

Comment: even if I use the `HashSet` the order of elements I am getting is always same, any idea why? Also, then nothing is different if I use `LinkedHashSet` or `HashSet` here.

Comment: @VishalZanzrukia You wouldn't be talking about the order the elements are _printed_ by the lambda passed to `filter()`, would you?

Comment: @Brain, No I am not talking about it, I am talking about the `Set` elements return by `collect` method.

Comment: @Vishal Zanzrukia: a `HashSet` is not a shuffle function. The order of its contained entries is not specified, point. It may look like being sorted or may look like matching the insertion order, still, it’s just a coincidence without any meaning.

Comment: This is not true, by default Collectors will return HashSet::new

Comment: @RuelosJoel It may do so, but it is not specified as doing so: *"There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the Set returned"*  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toSet--

Comment: @kaya3 yes thanks, even tho it's explicitly defined in the code, I missed out the java doc

Comment: @RuelosJoel You are mistaking implementation for specification.  The specification is forever; the implementation could vary across JDK versions or distributions (within the bounds of the specification, of course.)  So at best, you could conclude that _the version of the JDK you happen to be using today_ will return `HashSet`.

Comment: @BrianGoetz thanks for the explanation, in Java8 it returns HashSet, since the OP was asking for java 8